# How to set Spring Scope in XML

Tags: java, spring, proxy, scope

How can I go about setting the scope:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
```

in XML, instead of using `@Scope` annotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want XML based configuration then you can do it in following way:-

```
<bean id="YOUR_BEAN_ID" class="YOUR_FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASSNAME" scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include Bean definition in xml file as below

```
<bean id="Simple" class="com.example.Simple" scope="prototype" />
```